# Is this network configuration possible?

Tags: networking, router, home-networking

my family recently changes ISPs (from 12/1.5 to 30/5). The new service is bundled with phone and tv, so the provided modem handles all of these services from one box. Currently our wireless router is directly connected to the cable modem, which is downstairs next to the tv and phone. I would like to move the house networking upstairs as there's less foot traffic and chance of human interaction.

I also have a dell poweredge 2900 server that is currently configured as a hypervisor, and I'd like to configure a VM to act as a router/dhcp/etc. Is it possible to have a modem connected to a switch, and have the "router" connected to that switch? I have 4 powerline adapters so that's how I plan to expand the wired range of my network (shame the house doesn't have RJ-45 wiring).

Is this possible? I tried moving the current wireless router upstairs already, and it didn't work. But, maybe it would work with a proper network configuration.

The poweredge 2900 is just sitting there, so I'd like to get some use out of it (media server, active directory, web server, etc).

Modem -> powerline adapter

router/server -> powerline adapter1 (connection in)

router/server -> powerline adapter2 (connection out) also have 2 24port GB switches

media server  -> powerline adapter2 (it's a vm remember)

wireless AP1  -> powerline adapter3

wireless AP2  -> powerline adapter4

non server devices would connect to the appropriate access point. Other servers would go through powerline adapter2. And, could set up a virtual network to link the router vm to the other vms.

Just my thoughts. Your thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that some powerline adapters will let you have multiple logical networks on the same circuit. The logical network ID is usually assigned to the powerline adapter using a network name or an encryption key.

If your adapters can do that, you could put your WAN (modem, router in) on one logical network, while your LAN (router out, everything else) resides on a different logical network.

You can't put WAN and LAN on the same network segment because the cable modem needs to send DHCP broadcasts to assign your router a public IP address and the router needs to send DHCP broadcasts to assign private IP addresses to all other devices on the network.